# Dynamic tabs @ runtime and creating controls in it

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, tabs

Apologizes if this topic isnt in the right section, or if this has been already answered in another topic.

I am working with tabs, and have come across a business requirement where a need has arised to create tabs during runtime.

The request is to create a ADD Tab, REMOVE Tab buttons and to x amount of similar controls to be added at run time.

What would be the ideal approach to this -  since there might be validations we need to add as well, plus eventually the data pushed to a DB, etc 
Is there a sample project out there on codeplex/code gallery that I could take a look at ?

I am working with a windows forms application on VB 2010. C# examples work for me as well. I need a code sample that might guide me, open eneded answers welcomed - it will only help me learn.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS a starting point. To Add Tabs and controls to Tab use something like.

```
  TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Tabl Page");

        TextBox t = new TextBox(); 
        t.Left = 10;
        t.Top = 10;
        t.Visible = true;
        t.Width = 100;

        tp.Controls.Add(t);

        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
```

You might consider creating a template Tab Control so that this could be used over and over again and then think about how you want to bind these controls.